# Ajax success response and select option append

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to obtain the list of countries from my DB. The following are parts of the code:

**country.php:**

```
while ($country = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$data[] = $country['country'];
   }
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));
}
```

I am getting following response as:

```
{"response":["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American-Samoa","Andorra","Angola"......
```

**Ajax code:**

```
//country select
$( "#country" ).focus(function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'country.php',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);
var formoption = "";
$.each(data, function(v)
{
var val = data[v];
formoption += "<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>";
});

$('#countries').append(formoption);
      }
   });
});
```

and in the form:

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="form_input required">
<div id="countries"></div>
</select>
```

somehow it is not working and i am unable to find the reason. Please note that i am a JavaScript newbie. I am using it as part of Framework7 code.

Expecting help from experts.

Comment: Your url is "country".  You should provide the correct url to country.php

Comment: @Joseph_J It is okay.. Please note that I am using a redirect for php files in .htaccess so that it will display only as country. It is giving correct output of countries. Not the reason. 
I updated my post above to remove confusion.

Comment: what does your console.log(formoption) look like?

Comment: @Joseph_J It looks like:
0: "Afghanistan"
​​​
1: "Albania"
​​​
2: "Algeria"
​​​
3: "American-Samoa"
​​​
4: "Andorra"

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data.response);

Comment: @Pamela your code is ok, just remove div tag & change select id to countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('#countries').append(formoption);`

and remove div tag inside select tag & change select id to countries, use below html

```
<select id="countries" name="countries" class="form_input required">
</select>
```

you were wrapping options in `div` tag so thats not proper html.
options should directly be appended to select tag.

Refer below sample code

```js
$(function() {
  var resultFromAjax = {response: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American-Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola"]}
  var data = resultFromAjax.response

  var formoption = "";
  $.each(data, function(v) {
    var val = data[v]
    formoption += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>";
  });
  $('#countries').html(formoption);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countries" name="country" class="form_input required">
</select>
```

Comment: #country selects by id

Comment: @vinayakj Yes..You were absolutely correct. Only issue is that now i am getting the data as a single line CSV data in option dropdown. No dropdown functionality. Only a single line..

Comment: And my data is like:
{"response":["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American-Samoa","Andorra"

Comment: can you plz console.log the data & update your question with new code

Comment: ahh ok.. got it.. you have `response` keyword wrapped around, then try `var data = data.response; $.each(data, function(v)`

Comment: yep.. just `var data = data.response;
  var formoption = "";.... rest of the code` in your fiddle

Comment: $.each(data.response, function(v) { will result in undefined data

Comment: @vinayakj Thank you so much for the effort dear :). I was pulling my hair for the past 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

data only has one item named response which contains a json object.

when you json_encode in php, need to json.parse the response.

add before $.each...

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

then use... `data.response` in your "each" loop

```
$( "#country" ).focus(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'country.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {

        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
             $('#country')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value));
        });

    }
});
});
```

or something like that...

https://jsfiddle.net/0jLnnwrq/18/

Comment: Yes..I missed the Json.parse part. Something is wrong with my Json data as i am getting 
JSON.parse: unexpected character ERROR

Comment: I am trying locating the error from JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: @Pamela - see here to get ideal syntax for adding option to select ---> 
 https://jsfiddle.net/0jLnnwrq/18/

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

```
//country select
$( "#country" ).focus(function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'country.php',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);
var formoption = "";
obj = JSON.parse(data['response']);
for (i in obj) {
formoption += "<option value='"+obj[i]+"'>"+obj[i]+"</option>";
}

$('#countries').append(formoption);
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Yes i missed the JSON.parse part..
I am getting:
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$( "#country" ).focus(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'country.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            var formoption = "";
            $.each(data.response, function(k, v) {
                formoption += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</option>";
            });
            $('#countries').append(formoption);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: need to parse response i believe